# PL SQL Unit test report extraction through CLI is throwing "null connection not allowed" exception

Tags: oracle, unit-testing, reporting

I have a PL SQL Unit test defined with `name=AWARD_BONUS`, this test runs successfully in CLI using the following

```
sdcli unittest -run -test -name AWARD_BONUS -repo localDB -db localDB
```

The success of the above test is clearly visible in Oracle SQL Developer UI.

However when I try to generate output report against this unit test `AWARD_BONUS` using following command then

> null connection not allowed

exception is thrown back.

Command:

```
sdcli reports generate -report "junit_suite_report" -db localDB -file "C:\temp\mahesh1.html" -bind test_name=AWARD_BONUS**
```

The error description:

```
C:\Users\mahesh\Downloads\sqldeveloper-4.2.0.16.260.1303-x64\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin>sdcli reports generate -report "junittestreport" -db localDB -file "C:\temp\mahesh1.html" -bind test_name=AWARD_BONUS
NAVIGATOR HOOK PROCESS DESCRIPTORS LOAD TIME : 228ms
Command failed:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null connection not allowed
        at oracle.dbtools.db.DefaultConnectionIdentifier.<init>(DefaultConnectionIdentifier.java:29)
        at oracle.dbtools.db.DefaultConnectionIdentifier.createIdentifier(DefaultConnectionIdentifier.java:21)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.metadata.AbstractDisplayModel.getQuery(AbstractDisplayModel.java:393)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.metadata.AbstractDisplayModel.getQuery(AbstractDisplayModel.java:377)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.display.html.PLSQLHtmlGenerator.generateHtml(PLSQLHtmlGenerator.java:38)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.display.DisplayHtml.generateStyleSpecificHtml(DisplayHtml.java:391)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.display.DisplayHtml.generateModelHtml(DisplayHtml.java:325)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.display.DisplayHtml.generateHtml(DisplayHtml.java:261)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.controls.display.DisplayHtml.generate(DisplayHtml.java:202)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.report.headless.ReportsProcessor$GenerateReportTask.doWork(ReportsProcessor.java:101)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.report.headless.ReportsProcessor$GenerateReportTask.doWork(ReportsProcessor.java:39)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTask.call(RaptorTask.java:193)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at oracle.dbtools.raptor.backgroundTask.RaptorTaskManager$RaptorFutureTask.run(RaptorTaskManager.java:629)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any ways to get rid of this error ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an issue with the new SQL Developer version, we downgraded to the SQL Developer 4.0 and it works fine.